# <' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas

I had a Dataframe object from csv file in pandas. I wanted to check if any of these columns has negative values.
This is my Dataframe

```
d = {'country_region': ["Afganistan", "Albania","Poland"], 'confirmed': [23131, 323134,0]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

`(df2 < 0).any().any()`

or

`(df2.columns[1] < 0).any().any()`

Both times I get error '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Although i checked and confirmed column is int64. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please add a reproducible example in the form a simplified version of you data?

Comment: I can,sure. One moment

Comment: I did, what do you think?

Comment: So why not working `(df2.select_dtypes(np.number) < 0).any().any()`?

Comment: I did work great too, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `(df2 < 0).any().any()`, what happens is that the condition is being tested on all columns. Since you have some string columns, `str < 0`  doesn't make sense.

On the other case,  `df2.columns[1]` returns  `'confirmed'`, so the conditon `(df2.columns[1] < 0).any().any()` is the same as `('confirmed' < 0).any().any()`, which again is testing if a string is smaller than zero.

With just one column like this, `(df2[df2.columns[1]] < 0).any().any()` should work.

Comment: suppose I have 5 columns two of them are Strings, rest is integer type. How do I then can check for negative values? Using loop? Let's say  I have sth like that
region,deaths,recovered,alive, city how can i check it at deaths recovered and alive at the same time?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what @jezrael suggested should work. `(df2.select_dtypes(np.number) < 0).any().any()` will select all the numeric columns in you data and test the condition. A less elegant, but also effective approach if you have a small number of columns, could be to explicitly name them like `df2[['deaths','recovered','alive']]`.